# Use NOT EXIST and EXIST in LINQ c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Below is my SQL query I'm trying to covert to LINQ facing few challenges appreciate any help

```
if (@IDOut > 0 and not exists(select top 1'x' from tbl1    
       where Color = 'Red'    
       and VinId = @VinID    
       and ParentId = @ParentID)    
      and exists(select top 1'x' from tbl2 where DetailDesc = @DetailDesc    
       and PayId = 1))    
     insert tbl1(ParentId, Color, VinId, DateEntered,CreatedDateTime,MasterId)    
     values(@ParentID, 'Red', VinID, Getdate(),@IDOut)
```

Equivalent LINQ I tried

```
 var isRecordExist=((from t1 in tbl1 where !t1.Color.Equals(ColorEnum.Red)
                      && !t1.VinId==input.VinId
                      && !t1.ParentId==input.ParentId).Any()select t1).ToList()
//Not sure on how to add another query of EXIST 
   If(@IDOut>0 && isRecordExist.Count()>0)
   {
    //blah blah
   }
```

Comment: The functional equivalent of EXISTS can also be written as an OUTER JOIN where the materialized key of the JOIN is NOT NULL (or NULL for NOT EXISTS). That could be translated easily to LINQ. If you wanted to use a LAMBDA you could use .Any() which is more similar to an EXISTS.

Comment: You should use navigation properties in your class model and `!tbl1.Tbl2s.Any(...)` in the LINQ query. Show the class model + mapping code (if present) if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic isn't quite right. You need to use `==` not `!=`, and put the `!` on the outside. And you don't need to `.ToList` you can just use `.Any` on the whole thing.

```cs
var isRecordExist = !tbl1.Any(t1 =>
       t1.Color == ColorEnum.Red
    && t1.VinId == input.VinId
    && t1.ParentId == input.ParentId
   )
  && tbl2.Any(t2 =>
       t2.DetailDesc = input.DetailDesc
    && t2.PayId == 1
   );

if (IDOut > 0 && isRecordExist)
{
    //blah blah
}
```